# Ruby - Evenly distribute and interleave/interweave the elements of one array within another array of unknown length

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays of unknown length. The elements of one need to be evenly (as evenly as possible) distributed *within* the other.

Examples assuming the + elements in the arrays are placeholders for actual values. And I've omitted the array comma delimiters to remove visual noise and make the patterns more apparent.

```
a = [++++++++++] # 10 element array with + characters representing array items

b = [] # empty array
a.interweave(b) #=> [++++++++++]

b = [1]
a.interweave(b) #=> [+++++1+++++]

b = (1..2).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+++1+++2++++]

b = (1..3).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [++1++2+++3+++]  # any remaining + are distributed to the end chunks.

b = (1..4).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [++1++2++3++4++]

b = (1..5).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+1+2++3++4++5++]

b = (1..6).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+1+2+3+4++5++6++]

b = (1..7).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+1+2+3+4+5+6++7++]

b = (1..8).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8++]

b = (1..9).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+]

b = (1..10).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10]

b = (1..11).to_a
a.interweave(b) #=> [+,1,+,2,+,3,+,4,+,5,+,6,+,7,+,8,+,9,+,10,11] # the remaining elements from b are added to the end
```

A performant algorithm in Ruby is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
def weave(xx,yy)
  x = xx.dup
  y = yy.dup
  n_extra = [y.size - x.size + 1, 0].max
  y_extra = y.slice!(y.size - n_extra, n_extra)
  z = x.class.new
  loop do
    z += (x.slice!(0,((x.size)/(y.size+1.0)).floor) + y.slice!(0,1))
    break if y.empty?
  end
  z + x + y_extra
end         

x = ('-'*10).chars
  # => ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]

p weave(x, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
  # => ["-", "-", "a", "-", "-", "b", "-", "-", "-", "c", "-", "-", "-"]

p weave(x, ['a', 'b', 'c']).join # => "--a--b---c---"
p weave('----------', 'abc')     # => "--a--b---c---"

y = (1..12).each_with_object([]) {|i,a| a << ('a'..'z').to_a.first(i)}

y.each {|e| p weave(x, e).join}
"-----a-----"
"---a---b----"
"--a--b---c---"
"--a--b--c--d--"
"-a-b--c--d--e--"
"-a-b-c-d--e--f--"
"-a-b-c-d-e-f--g--"
"-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h--"
"-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-"
"-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j"
"-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-jk"
"-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-jkl"
```

Edit: I made a few changes to my original solution:

- added the first two lines of `weave` so the arguments would not be altered.
- simplified the loop.
- at @Kal's suggestion, removed `.join` from the end of `(arr + x + y_extra)`.
- changed `z = []` to `z = x.class.new` to allow `weave`'s arguments to be arrays or strings.

A word about `((x.size)/(y.size+1.0)).floor`.  Suppose `x = ['-','-','-','-','-','-'] and y = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.  Then:

- after the first iteration of the loop, `z => ['-', 'a']`, `x => ['-','-','-','-','-']` and `y => ['b', 'c']`.
- What remains of `x` is to be partitioned into `y.size+1.0 => 3.0` intervals, each with `x.size/3.0 => 5/3.0 => 1.67` elements if the elements of `x` could be divided.  As they can't be divided, and the larger groups are to be on the right, we strip off `1.67.floor => 1` element from `x`, append that and the next element of `y` to `z`, then repeat, until `y.empty? => true`.

Comment: Nice. Might be worth just moving the `#join` from the method to the method call, as in `y.each {|e| p weave(x.dup, e).join}`, because I think the OP wants an array returned normally. But other than that, does exactly what he asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Array
  def interweave(a2)
    a1 = self.dup
    arrays = [a1, a2].sort_by {|a| a.length}.reverse
    offset, remainder = arrays[0].length.divmod(arrays[1].length + 1)
    prev_jump = 0
    arrays[1].reverse.each_with_index do |e, i|
      remainder > 0 ? (adjust = 1; remainder -= 1) : adjust = 0
      jump = offset + adjust + 1
      arrays[0].insert( -(prev_jump + jump), e)
      prev_jump += jump
    end
    arrays[0]
  end
end

a1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

p a1.interweave [1] # => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..2).to_a # => [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..3).to_a # => [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..4).to_a # => [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..5).to_a # => [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..6).to_a # => [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..7).to_a # => [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..8).to_a # => [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..9).to_a # => [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0]
p a1.interweave (1..10).to_a # => [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10]
p a1.interweave (1..11).to_a # => [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11]
p a1.interweave (1..12).to_a # => [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11, 12]
```

I made it so the shortest array interweaves into the longest array before I noticed that you wanted leftovers to just be added at the end. Too tired to fix it now, but you can adjust as needed.